# In campaign, is it more profitable to keep buying colony modules or paying off debt / accumulating cash?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

I've noticed that after a certain number of purchased modules, the projected cash/week figure doesn't increase noticeably. My play style results in a lot of debt until the steady production can be established, and so I wonder if I'd be better off by paying it off until the end of the last sol or buying all available colony modules? Or maybe the most efficient is to find a middle ground between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. It's best to buy as many colony modules as possible, while maintaining the habitat/workplace ratio because one is useless without the other in terms of future profit. And future profit is the key thing here, because even if you end up in debt for the first several days, it will quickly be paid off by these huge colonies you've helped build, and you'll end up with a lot of cash later on.

Additionally, investing in an offworld launchpad early on can help buy more colony modules, which in turn will increase your future income.

Remember that each colony will keep giving you money, while opting to not buy colony modules will reduce that potential income in exchange for cash only for one day.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better in most cases to buy more colony modules.
There's two main components to buying colony modules, the increase in demand for that mission, and the $/week for future missions.  If you can buy a colony that will increase demand for your money maker, it seems to be better to buy the colony and then you can make more money for the same production.
It took me a while to realize how the colony modules affected demand for resources, so I think it's worthwhile to pause the game at the start and see what effect each module will have.
Note: If a industry module doesn't have enough workers, it won't cause the demand, so make sure to get habitats as well.

I'm not quite sure how much money each module provides per week, but buying all the modules I could every mission gave me plenty of money to buy employees for my main buildings.

My inclination is that buying modules is almost always better, just make sure to not have too much debt going into the last mission (I'm pretty sure that lowers your stock price).